# change admins for CDS-enabled environments

Tags: powershell, power-platform

I need to remove a lot of direct PowerPlatfrom environment admin assignments. The Set-AdminPowerAppEnvironmentRoleAssignment cmdlet only supports non-CDS environments.
Other than doing this manually, what other option do I have?